# Access applied coupons data via the "woocommerce_init" hook

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I want to access the `applied_coupons (WC_SESSION_HANDLER)` in the `woocommerce_init` hook so that prices will only show if a specified coupon is applied using the QR-Code or URL coupon.

I am currently using:

```
function hide_prices_testcop_coupon($order_id) {
    global $woocommerce;

    $wc_session = $woocommerce->session;
    
    var_dump($wc_session);
    
    $coupons = array();

    $coupons = $wc_session->applied_coupons; 
    
    //if (!empty($coupons)) {
        if (in_array('testfullsitecoupon', $coupons)) {
            echo '<h1 style="color:green;">Coupon is Applied</h1>';
        }else{
            echo '<h1 style="color:red;">Coupon is not Applied</h1>';
            add_filter('woocommerce_is_purchasable', '__return_false');
                add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_price_html', '' );
        }
    //}
    }
add_action( 'woocommerce_init', 'hide_prices_testcop_coupon');
```

With as result the `var_dump()` of wc_session:

```
object(WC_Session_Handler) #6503 (8) 
{ 
    ["_cookie":protected]=> string(55) "wp_woocommerce_session_bcb68b3833c74c2714057d937e0d99dc" 
    ["_session_expiring":protected]=> int(1665464629) 
    ["_session_expiration":protected]=> int(1665468229) 
    ["_has_cookie":protected]=> bool(false) 
    ["_table":protected]=> string(25) "wpze_woocommerce_sessions" 
    ["_customer_id":protected]=> string(32) "a2560019a017a8c5e1a84c4737b06d2c" 
    ["_data":protected]=> array(0) { } 
    ["_dirty":protected]=> bool(false)
}
```

I want to access the applied_coupon that is inside `["_data":protected]=>array(0)`

Any advice?

Answer (score 2):

Your code contains some mistakes/shortcomings or outdated code:

- `$order_id` does not apply when using the `woocommerce_init` action hook
- Using `global $woocommerce;` is the old way, just use `WC()` nowadays
- The current request is NOT for an administrative interface page, so use `if ( is_admin() ) return`;
- To determine if a variable is declared, use `isset()`
- When using `WC()->session->get( 'applied_coupons' )` and `new WC_Coupon( $coupon_code );` you have access to the *WC_Coupon Object* and all its properties

So you get:

```php
function action_woocommerce_init() {
    if ( is_admin() ) return;

    if ( isset( WC()->session ) ) {
        // Get applied coupons
        $applied_coupons = WC()->session->get( 'applied_coupons' ) !== null ? WC()->session->get( 'applied_coupons' ) : '';

        // NOT empty
        if ( ! empty ( $applied_coupons ) ) {
            // Dumps information about a variable
            echo '<pre>'; var_dump( $applied_coupons ); echo '</pre>';

            foreach ( $applied_coupons as $coupon_code ) {
                // WC_Coupon Object
                $coupon = new WC_Coupon( $coupon_code );

                // Get coupon discount type
                $discount_type = $coupon->get_discount_type();

                // Get coupon amount
                $coupon_amount = $coupon->get_amount();

                // Dumps information about a variable
                echo '<pre>'; var_dump( $discount_type ); echo '</pre>';
                echo '<pre>'; var_dump( $coupon_amount ); echo '</pre>';
            }
        } else {
            echo 'Applied coupons is empty! please refresh your web browser cache if necessary';
        }
    }
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_init', 'action_woocommerce_init' );
```